# Replicate a draggable image on the click of a button

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, uibutton, draggable

I am trying to create a draggable image upon button click in Objective C. For example, lets say the image is an X or an O or simply a dot. Each time I click an "Add" button, I would like for an image to appear.

After that I am looking for each image to be numbered. For example, the first addition of an image will be a circle with a 1 in it, and the second addition of an image will be a circle with a 2 in it and so on.